# How do I translate the following Java constructor code to Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Scala constructors

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myString = null;

    public MyClass() {
        myString = "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Scala you would just do

```
class MyClass {
  private var myString = "hello"
}
```

This doesn't look like the same thing, does it?  But let's look at the bytecode for what the Java code actually produces (let's call that class `JavaConstructor`):

```
public JavaConstructor();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aconst_null
   6:   putfield    #2; //Field myString:Ljava/lang/String;
   9:   aload_0
   10:  ldc #3; //String hello
   12:  putfield    #2; //Field myString:Ljava/lang/String;
   15:  return
```

Java has effectively copied the `private String myString = null;` into the constructor (note lines 5 and 6 where `null` is created and stored).  So that whole thing about setting `myString` to `null` was a complete waste of effort; you load it and then immediately overwrite it.

Now if we look at the corresponding Scala:

```
public ScalaConstructor();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #18; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   ldc #20; //String hello
   7:   putfield    #10; //Field myString:Ljava/lang/String;
   10:  return
}
```

we see it's as efficient as one would hope (and reflects the code).

Then the question is: why might you want to do it the way you did in Java?  Well, maybe you have multiple constructors and some of them will set `myString` and some won't!  Setting it to `null` is a way to remind yourself that you had better initialize it before you use it.

But Scala won't let you do that.  Scala really only allows one constructor; the others are just aliases that call that one constructor.  You can make it private and load it up with lots of parameters if you need to, but the point is that having multiple constructors some of which set critical data and some of which do not is actually a rather failure-prone process.  Better to do it just once, and write something like

```
private var myString = if (someParameter) "hello" else null
```

if you really need to do that.  Then again, maybe you only made it a `var` because you were trying to set it differently in different constructors.  With only one constructor, maybe there's no need for that:

```
private val myString = if (someParameter) "hello" else null
```

But maybe now that it's set correctly, we don't really need it to be private.

```
val myString = if (someParameter) "hello" else null
```

and maybe if it often isn't set, we should use an option instead:

```
val myString = if (someParameter) Some("hello") else None
```

and then you'd have something that looks more like idiomatic Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is a default one, it does not accept any arguments. It is equivalent to defining no constructor and setting a property myString to be "hello". Since you defined it as a val, it will be immutable (no equivalent to a java setter is available), but you can access the value of myString via the . notation (e.g. `myClass.myString`)

```
class MyClass {
  val myString = "hello"
}
```